# When designing a shopping cart in iOS, should I use core data or a global Cart class?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm normally a web developer so I immediately figured a global Cart class would be the way to go since it is semi-analogous to a web session.  I also consider Core Data to be for more permanent storage and thus not appropriate for a shopping cart.

However, I am not sure, given the structures and hierarchies that exist within objective-c how to implement a global instance of the cart class.  Should I store it in my appdelegate and access it via a method from there much like the managed object context?  Or should I just use core data since the MOC is already provided as a global instance via the appdelegate?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm in the midst of building a cart as well. Did you find a good solution?

Comment: I did end up going with a Core Data based shopping cart class, as for my project it was safe to assume one user per device.

Comment: @Darrrrren  Hmmm. I'm not too familiar with CD.. was that hard to implement?  I was thinking about using userDefaults to store the data if the app crashed or something. I have other issues I need to address before I get there though. :) Thanks

Comment: CoreData is probably a skill you'll want to learn anyway if you're serious about developing for iOS.  Although iOS dev changes so rapidly that perhaps CoreData is no longer relevant - I'd be surprised, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you're correct in that a singleton class would be ideal for this scenario, but having to deal with iOS and user actions within the device would lead me to say you should go down the CoreData road.

Consider instances where task switching / closing would cause a cart to be lost and wether or not you'd like the cart to remain after such cases?

Comment: That is a good point... obviously there could be instances of losing the current state of your program (heaven forbid a program crash, battery dies, etc).  I could maintain the state within a cart table in Core Data, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of very convenient shopping web sites go through a lot of trouble to make sure you can save, retain, restore your shopping cart; just because people have to task switch and it's a comfortable feeling to know your work will still be there when you return.

The same is true when you're shopping in an iOS app as far as I'm concerned. I would think it an absolute positive to know that my shopping cart information (which I might have spent time collecting) will only disappear when ***I*** want to remove it.

Which points to the information being permanent, which in turn points to using core data...

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  This seems to be the obvious choice when you consider the versatile nature of iOS devices... something I probably should have done before asking this question :-)